# Jquery menu ul toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have this menu:

```
           <ul id="submenu" class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vedella</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Minis de vedella</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vaca</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Poltre</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Porc Ibèric</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Pollastre</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Gall d´indi</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bou</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Each of the "#submenu" li fadeIn an ul sublist and hide the other sublists.

This are the sublist:

```
            <ul class="sublist first_sublist">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Normal </a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">All i Julivert</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Formatge Roquefort</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ceba</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="sublist second_sublist">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Mini-Hamburgueses</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Surtit Mini-Hamburgueses</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="sublist third_sublist">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Normal</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="sublist fourth_sublist">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Poltre</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="sublist fifth_sublist">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Porc ibèric de Gla</a></li>
            </ul>
```

and this css:

```
    .second_sublist, .third_sublist, .fourth_sublist, .fifth_sublist, .sixth_sublist{
        display: none;
    }
```

with this script:

```
$('#submenu li').click{
    $('#submenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
    $('.sublist.second_list').hide();
    $('.sublist.first_list').fadeIn();
});
```

The problem with the script is that it will get bigger if i have five sublists, cause i will have to make every click function per "#submenu" li.

Can someone help me to make it simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fKPVu/)**

Use the HTML-5 data attributes to store the corresponding sublists in them..
Approaching this way you can use a single handler to show/hide the sublists on the page.

**HTML**

```
 <ul id="submenu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="first_sublist">Vedella</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="second_sublist">Minis de vedella</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="third_sublist">Vaca</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="fourth_sublist">Poltre</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="fifth_sublist">Porc Ibèric</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-class="first_sublist">Pollastre</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Gall d´indi</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bou</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#submenu li a').on('click',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var className = $this.data("class");
    $('#submenu li a').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
    $('.sublist').hide();

    $('.'+ className).show();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of id for binding event so that you do not need id for binding the click event.

```
$('.clearfix li').click(function(){
    $('#submenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
    $('.sublist.second_list').hide();
    $('.sublist.first_list').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I would take:

**Update:** I forgot to mention, you could also [get rid of the clearfix class](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

**HTML**

```
<ul id="submenu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vedella</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Minis de vedella</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vaca</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Poltre</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Porc Ibèric</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Pollastre</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Gall d´indi</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bou</a></li>
 </ul>

<ul class="sublist">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Normal </a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">All i Julivert</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Formatge Roquefort</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ceba</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sublist">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Mini-Hamburgueses</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Surtit Mini-Hamburgueses</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sublist">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Normal</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sublist">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Poltre</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sublist">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Porc ibèric de Gla</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#submenu li').on('click',function(){
    $this = $(this);
    // move active class to current list item
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    // make sure all the sublists are hidden,
    // then determine the position of the list item
    // in the ul, and select the corresponding sublist
    // ex: selecting the 2nd list item in submenu would
    // find the 2nd sublist and fadeIn
    $('.sublist').hide().eq($this.index()).fadeIn();
});
```

Of course, this means the sublists would have to be in the same order as the submenu list items.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it later and tell you

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you have done your structure this way or if you change this way:

```
<ul id="submenu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vedella</a>
        <ul class="sublist first_sublist">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Normal </a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">All i Julivert</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Formatge Roquefort</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Ceba</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


$('#submenu li').click(function(){
    $('#submenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
    $('.sublist.second_list').hide();
    $('ul',this).fadeIn();
});
```